# How to apply Break lines in React Modal?

Tags: reactjs, antd

As title.
I have an array that contains some messages that I want to show to End user:

```
var Errors=[
    "Your name is empty!",
    "Your tags are empty!",
    "No zip files to upload!",
];
```

How could I use the Modal.error call and show a dialog with break lines:

Your name is empty!
Your tags are empty!
No zip files to upload!

That is one line for a string in the array?  I've tried use <br /> to the Errors.join() function call and I see the less than and great than marks; I've tried to use "\r\n" to Errors.join() but I havent' got the effects.
Sorry about that English is not my mother language.  I could add some information that I didn't provide yet.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```js
Modal.error({
    title: 'This is an error message',
    content: <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:`${Errors.join('<br/>')}`}}/>,
  });
```

Comment: Sorry for response so late but it works very well!  Thank you!